# How to make drop-down default to blank

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, drop-down-menu, dropdown, asp.net-core-2.1

When I go to my web page, it has a drop down list with a name already selected. I want that it to default to a blank value every time someone goes to that page. They will need to type in that blank space.

```
<select asp-for="OwnerId" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.OwnerList"></select>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are a few pieces of information that would be useful here. First, which version of ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Core are you using? Second, what do you mean by "they will need to type in that blank space"? Since this is a `<select />` list, users aren't able to type in new values. Do you just mean that the user must select a value, instead of it defaulting to the first value?

Comment: I ma looking to show just and empty space as default instead of the info that defaults there now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use append/prepend or appendTo/prependTo to add new empty option to the beginning or end of the list with jquery.

Make sure to run the script after document loaded:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#OwnerId").prepend('<option></option>').val('');
});
```

or

```js
$(function () {
    $('<option>', { value: '' }).appendTo($("#OwnerId"));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<select asp-for="OwnerId" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.OwnerList"></select>
```

The way i found to have that empty space in the drop down show first was this:

```
<select asp-for="OwnerId" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.OwnerList">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Thanks for the help! This was my first post and got help almost immediately. This is html, next time i will know more about how to post properly.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure `Model.OwnerList` first value is an empty value (so it is the default value for the list).

Heres an example of creating an empty `SelectListItem` to place as your first item in `Model.OwnerList`

```
var empty = new SelectListItem() {
    Text = "",
    Value = ""
};
```

2) Make sure `OwnerId` doesn't already contain a value

If `OwnerId` already has a value, it will select the first item it finds in `Model.OwnerList` that matches that value

Do these two things and you will have an empty selection on load

Comment: Where should i apply the variable?

Comment: i think i am using ASP.NET MVC

Comment: What is Model.OwnerList? It should be a List<SelectListItem> or something like that, you want to add that variable to Model.OwnerList in the first position